# How to implement 10 fold cross validation?

Tags: java, machine-learning, cross-validation

I have a code to perform 10 fold cross-validation on a dataset. The code is created by dividing the data into k-1 parts for training and the remaining part for testing. I want to see if my code is correct or not
My code is:

```
 Dataset data = data1;
        Dataset[] folds = data.folds((10), new Random(100));
        Dataset training = new DefaultDataset();
        Dataset testing = new DefaultDataset();
        int[] tr = {0, 2, 3, 4,5, 6,7, 8, 9};
        int[] te = {1};   
        for (int i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            training.addAll(folds[tr[i]]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < te.length; i++) {
            testing.addAll(folds[te[i]]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming code in the line

```
data.folds((10), new Random(100));
```

is correctly sampling 10 percent of the data, and return all 10 folds to output variable, separating the dataset looks correct.

However, you should remember to iterate k times for k-fold cross validation and average results.

[image: k iterations for k fold cross validation]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#/media/File:K-fold_cross_validation_EN.jpg